# P/Invoke syntax - Am I translating my C++ function correctly in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, interop, pinvoke

A quick disclaimer: I'm very new to P/Invoke, so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question.

Here's my function signature in C++:

```
HRESULT SomeFunction( 
    _Out_ unsigned long *count,
    _Outptr_result_buffer_(*count) GUID **ids,
    _In_ const PCWSTR filter
)
```

And I'm trying to P/Invoke it as such in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct GUID
{
   public int a;
   public short b;
   public short c;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=8)] 
   public byte[] d;
}

[DllImport("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint="SomeFunction")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
private static extern Int64 SomeFunction
(
    out ulong count, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    out GUID[] ids,
    string filter
);
```

I know my code gets reaches the C++ function (I can see this in windbg) and there is *no* crash, but from what I can tell, the parameters aren't being passed correctly. My guess is that I've messed up my P/Invoke translation in C#, but I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do .Net GUIDs work when mapped against native GUIDs? I seem to remember using them in some of my code, but it may be imagination.

Comment: @Vlad Except the function has a return value and two output parameters, so it certainly can't map quite like that. Using `out` sounds right (not entirely sure).

Comment: An 'unsigned long' is not necessarily equiavelent to a ulong. It's more likely to be a uint.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I think I found my solution (see below)

Comment: Somebody has to release the memory for the returned array.  This code will bomb on Vista and up when the pinvoke marshaller tries to do it.  You cannot pinvoke this function safely, the 2nd argument should be a GUID* so the caller can supply the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I found my solution...

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint="SomeFunction")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
private static extern int SomeFunction
(
    out uint count, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    out GUID[] ids,
    [InAttribute()] 
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
    string filter
);
```